# Fama French Factor Loadings for European Markets

Tags: fama-french, european

I am working on a paper where I have to check how changes in ESG scores relate to stock returns. My sample firms are mostly from European markets(eg. STOXX 600 index) and I need to adjust Fama French factors in my model . Could anyone please help me out where can I get those factor loadings for European markets?

Thanks

Comment: You can find data on European factors on [Ken French's website](http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/data_library.html). Factor loadings are estimated from running regressions.

Comment: Thank you very much @Kevin